# Validation formula is not saved as a function

Tags: php, excel, libreoffice, phpspreadsheet

I'm generating XLSX files in PHP, using PhpSpreadsheet, and trying to implement a dynamic drop-down list as a validation rule.

```
    $validator = $cell->getDataValidation();

    $validator->setType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
    $validator->setErrorStyle( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
    $validator->setAllowBlank(false);
    $validator->setShowInputMessage(true);
    $validator->setShowErrorMessage(true);
    $validator->setShowDropDown(true);
    $validator->setFormula1("=OFFSET(values!\$D\$2:\$D\$6,OFFSET(values!\$B\$2,MATCH(A2,values!\$A\$2:\$A\$3)-1,0),0,OFFSET(values!\$C\$2,MATCH(A2,values!\$A\$2:\$A\$3)-1,0),1)");
```

When I use a simple range expression like `values!$A$2:$A$20`, then it works properly. But when a function is used, like above, then after opening the sheet in Libreoffice, the validation formula doesn't start with an `=` (equals) sign, and the validation rule doesn't work.

When I edit the formula manually in the validation settings for the specific cell, and add an `=` at the beginning, then everything works fine.
Is there a solution for adding a formula in the validation rule?

Update: Now I tried it with Excel 2010, but that has just removed the validation rules as a form of `recovery` of unreadable data. It works fine when only range expressions are used, so my guess is that PhpSpreadsheet messes up the format.